# Python and Pandas: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, json, pandas, encoding, python-2.x

After using Pandas to read a json object into a `Pandas.DataFrame`, we only want to `print` the first year in each pandas row. Eg: if we have `2013-2014(2015)`, we want to print `2013`

**Full code [(here)](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9e7b4932e9adf8e6f1fa)**

```
x = '{"0":"1985\\u2013present","1":"1985\\u2013present",......}'
a = pd.read_json(x, typ='series')
for i, row in a.iteritems():
    print row.split('-')[0].split('—')[0].split('(')[0]
```

the following error occurs:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1333-d8ef23860c53> in <module>()
      1 for i, row in a.iteritems():
----> 2     print row.split('-')[0].split('—')[0].split('(')[0]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Why is this happening? How can we fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your json data strings are unicode string, which you can see for example by just printing one of the values:

```
In: a[0]
Out: u'1985\u2013present'
```

Now you try to split the string at the unicode `\u2031` (EN DASH), but the string you give to `split` is no unicode string (therefore the error `'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2` - the EN DASH is no ASCII character).

To make your example working, you could use:

```
for i, row in a.iteritems():
    print row.split('-')[0].split(u'—')[0].split('(')[0]
```

Notice the `u` in front of the uncode dash. You could also write `u'\u2013'` to split the string.

For details on unicode in Python, see https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html